# setTimout inside for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, timeout

The code:

```
for(var a=0;a<=60;a++){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("a").innerHTML=a;
    },1000);
}
```

It displays 61 with no delay at all. I can not see any reason why it would do that...

Comment: Are you sure it didn't wait 1 second before displaying 61? You have 60 functions that all run at the same time, 1 second after the loop.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is setInterval implementation.

Comment: I see that this question has been marked as a duplicate, but I looked at the question/answer that was referred to, and I do not share the same conclusion as @alexander.

The reason you are not getting a delay is because setTimeout will call the function once before delaying and calling again.  You need to get rid of the for loop and, instead, have a counter increment within the setTimeout method.  I would give a clean example of this, but I unable to because of the question being marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is clearly an implementation of setInterval.

```js
  var a = 0;

  function displayIncreament() {
    if (a <= 60) {
      document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = a;
      a++;
    } else {
      clearInterval(IncreamentInterval)
    }

  }

  var IncreamentInterval = setInterval(displayIncreament, 1000)
```

```html
<span id="a"></span>
```